# API path different from dev to test to prod. How do I avoid changing between deployments?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-web-api

Using ASP.Net WebAPI and javascript/jquery.

I have the following JScript code:`var apiUrl = "/api/myService/myMethod/`

```
  $.GetJSON(apiUrl+"/"+myValue).done(function(data){more code here});
```

In my dev environment this works fine. But when I move it to our test server it becomes a web application in a subdirectory called MyApp. Is there a way to tell the javascript to go to the root of the app instead of the root of the site? I want to avoid having to prepend the "/MyApp/" to the front of that string.

Something lie `var test="~/api/myService/myMethod/"`

Comment: You could just add a configuration to your web config that is read in and passed onto javascript. That way your js code doesn't need to be concerned with the detail of which server it's calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the following JScript code:var apiUrl = "/api/myService/myMethod/

Don't have such code. Never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. You should always use helpers when dealing with urls. So for example you could have this in a global variable in your Layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var apiUrl = '@Url.Route("DefaultApi", new { controller = "values", httproute = "" });';
</script>
```

You are undoubtedly noticing the `httproute = ""` route parameter I used in order to indicate to the URL helper to use the Web API routes and not your MVC routes (which are 2 entirely different things).

But in most cases you don't even need that. The url that you are passing to this `$.getJSON` function could be part of your DOM. For example you never call this `$.getJSON` function like that in the wild. You usually call it to unobtrusively AJAXify an anchor or a form. So the url could already be part of the DOM. For example let's suppose that you wanted to AJAXify an anchor. Great, go ahead and write this anchor to be pointing to the correct url:

```
@Html.RouteLink(
    "click me", 
    "DefaultApi", 
    new { httproute = "", controller = "values", id = "123" }, 
    new { id = "mylink" }
)
```

Cool, now AJAXify it:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        $.getJSON(this.href, function(result) {
            alert('success');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

See how you no longer need to be hardcoding any urls in your javascript? You just use javascript to unobtrusively enhance what's already present in the DOM. And this is generated by proper url helpers that ensure that the correct url is created respecting your route definitions. This way you could change the pattern of your routes in a single place (wherever you configure your routes) and you never need to worry about your views.

Comment: Ok starting to make sense. Thanks

Comment: How would you go about picking up a value from a text box instead of the "id" as you have it?

Comment: You could have the following url generated: `var apiUrl = '@Url.Route("DefaultApi", new { controller = "values", id = "__id__", httproute = "" });'`. And then simply `apiUrl.replace('__id__', valueFromYourTextBox);`.

Comment: @Url.Route or @Url.RouteUrl??

Comment: It's `RouteUrl` as it allows you to specify the route name.